# Using Asterisk queues with extensions instead of channels/agents

Tags: queue, asterisk, channel

Our Asterisk PBX is set up with one extension "xxx" to dial an employee.
The logic in our diaplan will decide which channel to call for this extension, but there is no channel xxx.
This works fine for internal calling, but the queues are now all empty, since there is no channel "xxx" anymore.
I've tried creating an app_agent_pool and assigning agents with the xxx extensions, but whatever I do, the queues remain empty.

Is there any way to direct a call from a queue to an xxx extension that is not defined in sip.conf and is not a channel, and let the dialplan handle the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Local channel and dial to dialplan.

```
agent=> Local/xxx@mycontext/n
```

For normal operation you also should check hints&states

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Extension+State+and+Hints

Comment: Thanks! I was using the wrong context, thanks for clearing that out!